# How to create multiple RBS stores for a single content database

Tags: 2010, sql-server-2012, rbs, remote-blob-storage

I have a sharepoint content database and one RBS store configured with this content db.
and it can be possible to create one another RBS store for the same contet database.

this sharepoint web application  has one site collection.

i have an issue this RBS store has size exceeds 4 TB so for this reason i want to prepare another storage for second RBS store  for same content database.

or

what are the other options available for best practise if a sharepoint content db size exceeds 4 TB?